# Finitely Generated Free Group to Finitely Generated Free Monoid

Tags: group-homomorphism, free-groups, monoid, morphism

Let $F_n$ be the free group on $n$ generators $u_1,...,u_n$ and $M_n$ the free monoid on $n$ generators $v_1,...,v_n$. Would $u_i \to v_i$ and $u_i^{-1} \mapsto v_i$ extend to a well-defined map that is something like a homomorphism?

Comment: That's not well-defined, is it? $u_i u_u^{-1}$ should be sent to the identity, but it's actually sent to $v_i v_i$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Ah! Dang! You're right. Is there any other mapping that would be something like a homomorphism? Some sort of projection, perhaps? I'm just sort of making things up!

Comment: Nothing springs to mind, but then I am tired, ill, and rusty :)

Comment: @PatrickStevens Perhaps $u_i^{-1} \mapsto 1_{M_n}$ for every $i$? Would that work? I might lose too much information doing that, though. Nope! Same problem!

Comment: I think that's not well-defined either, for basically the same reason: $u_i u_i^{-1}$ is sent to $u_i$ when it should be sent to the identity. I think you're going to have to insist on some kind of cancellation law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work, and more generally if $G$ is any group and $M$ is a free monoid, the only (monoid) homomorphism from $G$ to $M$ is the map that sends every element of $G$ to $1$.  Indeed, suppose $f:G\to M$ is a homomorphism and let $g\in G$.  Then $f(g)f(g^{-1})=f(1)=1$.  But the only way two elements of $M$ can have product $1$ is if both elements are $1$ (for instance, because every element of $M$ can uniquely be written as a word in the free generators and the only way to concatenate two words to get an empty word is if the two words are also empty).  Thus $f(g)=1$.